# how to use .htaccess with nginx and where to put it?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, url-rewrite-module

I am new to nginx and I don't know how to use .htaccess with nginx and where to put the generated code in nginx configuration.could anyone please help me to convert this to nginx?

Here is my .htaccess file

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(admin)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [^a-z](cast|char|convert|declare|delete|drop|exec|insert|meta|script|select|set|truncate|update)[^a-z] [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) - [F]
RewriteEngine On
# redirect with username
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(admin|assets|include)(.*)?$ /$1$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^media/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ media.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^media/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ media.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/.]+)$ tag.php?tag=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/.]+)/$ tag.php?tag=$1 [QSA,L]
# turn on the mod_rewrite engine
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
# IF the request filename with .php extension is a file which exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
# AND the request is not for a directory
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
# redirect to the php script with the requested filename



</IfModule>
```

Please help me to convert this to nginx and guide me where to exactly put this codes. Thank you!

Comment: nginx don't use (read) .htaccess, only apache

Comment: yeah but there's a way to convert htaccess to nginx right?

Comment: Yes. check this -> https://ploi.io/documentation/server/how-can-i-use-htaccess-with-nginx

Answer (score 0):

Nginx doesn't use htaccess files; you have to specify the rules in your Nginx site configurations say, `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my-site.com.conf`.You can use service like [this](https://winginx.com/en/htaccess) for converting your existing htaccess file to Nginx conf, but after converting you have to recheck if anything is wrong.

Below is conf converted from above service to get some idea about config change needed, but there may be some change related to your current nginx configuration.

```
location ~ \.(admin)$ { 
} 
location ~ /$ { 
} 
location / { 
 if ($query_string ~* "[^a-z](cast|char|convert|declare|delete|drop|exec|insert|meta|script|select|set|truncate|update)[^a-z]"){ 
  return 403; 
 } 
 if (!-e $request_filename){ 
       rewrite ^/(admin|assets|include)(.*)?$ /$1$2 redirect; 
  } 
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1\.php break; 
} 
location /user { 
    rewrite ^/user/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /user.php?username=$1;
    rewrite ^/user/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /user.php?username=$1; 
} 
location /media { 
        rewrite ^/media/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /media.php?id=$1; 
        rewrite ^/media/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /media.php?id=$1; 
 } 
 location /tag { 
     rewrite ^/tag/([^/.]+)$ /tag.php?tag=$1 break; 
     rewrite ^/tag/([^/.]+)/$ /tag.php?tag=$1 break; 
 }
```

Comment: there's nothing in my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ folder it is empty. i have added the server configuration in /etc/nginx/sites-available what to do ?

Comment: you can symlink with `ln -s /etc/sites-available/foo.com.conf /etc/sites-enabled/foo.com.conf` then reload nginx using ` sudo nginx -s reload`

Comment: >RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [^a-z](cast|char|convert|declare|delete|drop|exec|insert|meta|script|select|set|truncate|update)[^a-z] [NC]


Oh lord.... Please don't write your own WAF.    Pretty please?